# Needed solve on out of stack and on assert and dynamics

Tags: prolog

This is my program and I met problem on running `foul(X)`.
Also I want to ask about the use of assert and dynamics.
And is there any other method to make facts into the database on the user side?(not typing into the codes).

```
%! program name: what to eat tonight
%! author: bearharry
%! database part 
%! characteristics
:- discontiguous char/2.
char(pork,redmeat).
char(beef,redmeat).
char(bird,whitemeat).
char(bird,meat).
char(fish,whitemeat).
char(redmeat,meat).
char(chicken,bird).
char(duck,bird).
char(pepper,spicy).
char(salt,salty).
char(sugar,sweet).
char(soysauce,salty).
char(vinegar,sour).
char(rice,carbohydrates).
char(saffron,spice).
char(bread,gluten).
char(herbs,spice).
char(bread,carbonhydrates).
char(shrimp,seafood).
char(bun,bread).
char(coleslaw,cabbage).
char(vegetable,vegatable).
char(lettuce,vegetable).
char(kaiserroll,bread).
char(onion,vegatable).
char(probvolonecheese,cheese).
char(garlic,spice).
char(relish,vegatable).
char(bittergourd,bitter).
char(squid,seafood).
char(pickle,vegatable).
char(cheese,cheese).
char(ketchup,sour).
char(chili,spicy).
char(mayonaise,protein).
char(mayonaise,sour).
char(mayonaise,sweet).
%! ingredient layer1
ingredient(pork).
ingredient(beef).
ingredient(chicken).
ingredient(duck).
ingredient(herbs).
ingredient(meat).
ingredient(shrimp).
ingredient(bun).
ingredient(coleslaw).
ingredient(lettuce).
ingredient(kaiserroll).
ingredient(onion).
ingredient(probvolonecheese).
ingredient(mastard).
ingredient(relish).
ingredient(pickle).
ingredient(cheese).
ingredient(squid).
ingredient(garlic).
ingredient(bittergourd).
ingredient(egg).
subtype(whitemeat).
subtype(redmeat).
subtype(bird).
subtype(bread).
condiment(pepper).
condiment(salt).
condiment(sugar).
condiment(soysauce).
condiment(vinegar).
condiment(spice).
condiment(ketchup).
condiment(chili).
condiment(mayonaise).
%! ingredient 
contain(zafranipulao,[rice,saffron]).
contain(vegetablepulao,[rice,vegetable]).
contain(vegetablebiryani,[rice,vegetable,herbs]).
contain(dumpukhtbhandar,[rice,meat]).
contain(shrimpbriyani,[rice,shrimp,herbs,spices]).
contain(carolinaporksandwich,[pork,bun,spice,coleslaw]).
contain(thehogheaven,[pork,sausage,bun]).
contain(openfacedleannmean,[turkey,toast,spice,coleslaw]).
contain(pulledchickenbreastsandwich,[chicken,mayonaise,lettuce,ketchup]).
contain(thezmansandwich,[beef,probvolonecheese,onion,kaiserroll]).
contain(hotdog,[mastard,relish,onion,tomato,pickle,pepper,bun]).
contain(chillcheesedog,[onion,chili,cheese,bun]).
contain(burger,[beef,lettuce,tomato,onion,pickles,ketchup,mayonaise,bun]).
contain(baconburger,[bacon,mayonaise,lettuce,tomato,bun]).
contain(char-broiledchickensandwich,[chicken,bun,mayonaise,tomato,lettuce]).
contain(garlicsaltandpeppersquidballs,[squid,garlic,salt,pepper]).
contain(bittermelonfriedbeef,[bittergourd,beef,salt]).
contain(bitterscrambledeggs,[bittergourd,egg,salt]).
contain(scrambledeggswithshrimps,[egg,shrimps]).
contain(porkscrambledeggs,[pork,egg]).
%! dish layer1 
dish(zafranipulao).
dish(vegetablepulao).
dish(vegetablebiryani).
dish(dumpukhtbhandar).
dish(shrimpbriyani).
dish(carolinaporksandwich).
dish(thehogheaven).
dish(openfacedleannmean).
dish(pulledchickenbreastsandwich).
dish(thezmansandwich).
dish(hotdog).
dish(chillcheesedog).
dish(burger).
dish(baconburger).
dish(char-broiledchickensandwich).
dish(garlicsaltandpeppersquidballs).
dish(bittermelonfriedbeef).
dish(bitterscrambledeggs).
dish(scrambledeggswithshrimps).
dish(porkscrambledeggs).
%! restaurant selling
sell(hoilok,garlicsaltandpeppersquidballs).
sell(hoilok,bittermelonfriedbeef).
sell(hoilok,bitterscrambledeggs).
sell(hoilok,porkscrambledeggs).
sell(hoilok,scrambledeggswithshrimps).
sell(portillo,hotdog).
sell(portillo,chillcheesedog).
sell(portillo,burger).
sell(portillo,baconburger).
sell(portillo,char-broiledchickensandwich).
sell(deewanbanquet,zafranipulao).
sell(deewanbanquet,vegetablepulao).
sell(deewanbanquet,vegetablebiryani).
sell(deewanbanquet,dumpukhtbhandar).
sell(deewanbanquet,shrimpbriyani).
sell(joeskansacity,carolinaporksandwich).
sell(joeskansacity,thehogheaven).
sell(joeskansacity,openfacedleannmean).
sell(joeskansacity,pulledchickenbreastsandwich).
sell(joeskansacity,thezmansandwich).
%! restaurant layer2
rest(portillo).
rest(hoilok).
rest(deewanbanquet).
rest(joeskansacity).
%! dynamics
:- dynamic foulchar/1.
%!:- dynamic rchar/1.
foulchar(vegetables).
%! rules
%! inherit of characteristics
char(Sth,Char) :-
    (   (ingredient(Sth);subtype(Sth);condiment(Sth)),
        char(Sth,Subtype),
        char(Subtype, Char));
    (   dish(Sth),
        contain(Sth,Ingredients),
        member(Ingredient,Ingredients),
        char(Ingredient,Char);
    (   rest(Sth),
        sell(Sth,Dish),
        char(Dish,Char))).
%! foul dish if it contain characters that fouled through foulchar(char)
%! or foulin(Ingredient)
% ! foul restaurant if it doesen't sell dish that is not fouled or
% provide food that with the required characteristic.
%! foulchar(Char):-assert(foulchar(Char)). 
%! rchar(Ingredient):-assert(rchar(Char)).
foul(Sth) :-
     dish(Sth),
     foulchar(X),
     char(Sth, X).
foul(Sth) :-
    foulin(Ingredient),
    contain(Sth,Ingredients),
    member(Ingredient,Ingredients). 
foul(Sth) :-
       rest(Sth),
       sell(Sth,Dish),
       not(foul(Dish)).
%! foul(Sth) :-
%!  rchar(X),
%!  not(char(Sth,X))).
%! list the dish that can be made with the ingredient provided,
listdish(X,Avaliables) :-
    contain(X,Ingredients),
    subset(Ingredients,Avaliables).
%! list the restaurant left
listrest(Restaurant) :-
    sell(Restaurant, Dish),
    not(foul(Dish)),
    not(foul(Restaurant)).
```

Comment: Please read this carefully and edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also please properly format your code. Indentation is key to seeing the code structure clearly. Read this to learn how to format on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.